# Hyperlinks in an Embed not working (discord.py)

Tags: python, hyperlink, discord, discord.py

Tricky issue here...

I have a list of dicts (top_x_games) that I'm looping through and adding certain elements from it to a string.  The problem is that the `[here](your_link_goes_here)` discord syntax for adding a clickable link inside a message doesn't appear to be working.  This works in cases for a single string so I'm not sure why it isn't here.

```
description2 = ""
for game in top_x_games:
        description2 += f"#{game['rank']}) [{game['name']}]({steam_api.get_game_url(game['name'])}) with f"{(game['player_count'])} players\n"
```

An example of the result has been this, where randomly 2 out of the 10 correctly hyperlink the url to the `{game['name']}` value but the others don't :
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKhSs.png)

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because a URLs generated using `steam_api.get_game_url` contain spaces. URl can not contains spaces therefore Discord doesn’t format them as hyperlinks.

Your problem is not connected to Discord or discord.py.